# Local variable assignment in SQL subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute a SQL query containing multiple subqueries and then assign some parts of it to a local variable. Unfortunately I'm having issues getting the syntax correct.

My query is as follows

```
declare @temp1 varchar(200)
declare @temp2 varchar(200)

select case when cnt>0 then 'RouteA' else 'RouteB' end as Route from
( select 
        (
          (select case when (req.Avg > 10) then 1 else 0 end from
            (select count(val) as Avg from T1) req) +

          (select case when (req.Avg > 10) then 1 else 0 end from
            (select count(val) as Avg from T2) req)                               
       ) as cnt) t
```

What I need to do is assign the value of the following subquery to @temp1:

```
(select case when (req.Avg > 10) then 1 else 0 end from
(select count(val) as Avg from T1) req)
```

and this subquery to temp2:

```
(select case when (req.Avg > 10) then 1 else 0 end from
(select count(val) as Avg from T2) req)
```

I've tried doing this a number of ways but keep getting syntax errors.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you,
Charlie

Comment: In one query you can either assign variables, or return a result set, you can't do both.

Comment: Although it won't let you assign variables and return a result set, you may want to learn about the [`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx?ppud=4) clause. It can be used with a table variable among other tricks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix variable assignment and a result set in the same select. Your SQL also has other problems. I dont think you can select from the result of a count().

Why dont you assign your variables, then do the select on them if you need to?

```
IF (select count(val) as Avg from T1) > 10 
  SET @temp1 = 1
ELSE
  SET @temp1 = 0
```

You could also do this in a select if you need to

```
SELECT @temp1 = CASE WHEN (select count(val) as Avg from T1) > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```